# How to create Dynamic TableLayout from JsonArray in android

Tags: android, json, dynamic, tablelayout

I m new to android and want a dynamic tablelayout in my app. The json below is posted and I want a table layout showing title as "Service" tag(washing) as first table row and below its details:"Cost" &"quantity". Then a sleek black line & then title 2 (service:ironing) and its details.I dont know how to iterate through json fields.Please help me on this.

[{"Label":"5kg","Service":"Washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"100","Quantity":"till 5kg"},{"Label":"5kg - 7kg","Service":"Washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"200","Quantity":"5kg - 7 kg"},{"Label":"Above 7kg","Service":"Washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"300","Quantity":"Above 7kg"},{"Label":"5kg","Service":"ironing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"100","Quantity":"5kg"},{"Label":"5kg - 7kg","Service":"ironing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"200","Quantity":"5kg - 7kg"},{"Label":"Above 7kg","Service":"ironing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"300","Quantity":"Above 7kg"},{"Label":"5kg","Service":"woollen washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"100","Quantity":"5kg"},{"Label":"5kg - 7kg","Service":"woollen washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"200","Quantity":"5kg - 7kg"},{"Label":"Above 7kg","Service":"woollen washing","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"300","Quantity":"Above 7kg"},{"Label":"5kg","Service":"washing and folding","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"100","Quantity":"5kg"},{"Label":"5kg - 7kg","Service":"washing and folding","Service_type":"Normal Delivery","Cost":"200","Quantity":"5kg - 7kg"}]

Answer (score 0):

there is an java API for json

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html  [edit: not on android]

on android there is GSON https://github.com/google/gson

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

or using the built-in functions of android: [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

dynamic table layouts are i.e. in this thread:
[Android : Dynamic TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336880/android-dynamic-tablelayout)

Comment: Could you please provide a code instead to count all these and create a tablelayout, its getting confusing for me as I dont know how to craete dynamic tablelayout+iterate through json accordingly. Although I am trying to solve this but not getting upto the level.

Comment: Is there any short way, I need it badly in less time